# Is $\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{2}]$ Noetherian?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, noetherian

I am a bit confused with the question wether $\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{2}]$ is a Noetherian ring or not.

I would say that $\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{2}]$ is a Noetherian ring.

Reason : $\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{2}]$ is a finitely generated $\mathbb{Z}$-module. Hence, it is Noetherian as a $\mathbb{Z}$-module. Since every ideal of $\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{2}]$ is also a $\mathbb{Z}$-module, it is a Noetherian ring.

Is this correct ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Another way: Its the localization of $\mathbb{Z}$ at the multiplicative set $\{1, 2, 4, 8, \dots\}$. So a sequence of ideals in $\mathbb{Z}[1/2]$ gives a sequence of ideals in $\mathbb{Z}$ by general properties of localization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\Bbb Z[\frac12]$ is **not** a finitely generated $\Bbb Z$-module.

But $\Bbb Z[\frac12]$ is a finitely generated $\Bbb Z$-algebra.
It is isomorphic to a quotient of $\Bbb Z[X]$ which is Noetherian
(by the Hilbert basis theorem) and so is itself Noetherian.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful answer. I did not know the Hilbert basis theorem. I just looked it up and now understand it :).

Answer (score 1):

For $\alpha\in\mathbb C$,
$\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$ is a finitely generated $\mathbb{Z}$-module iff $\alpha$ is integral over $\mathbb Z$, which $1/2$ is not.

Comment: Thanks for this important remark. I will need it.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{2}]$ is *not* a finitely generated $\mathbb{Z}$-module, but finitely generated as $\mathbb{Z}$-algebra.